# How to remove query string using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make the following redirection (301) using .htaccess (apache 2.2)
*/?q=/shop/ to *
The string is on the end.

My code on [the sandbox](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) is:

```html
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^q=/shop/$
RewriteRule      (.*)               $1?     [R=permanent]
```

And the result in the sandbox has /%3F?q=/shop/ on the end. 
The htaccess on my website with apache 2.2 is not working too. 
What is wrong?

Comment: Did you clear your browser caches?

Comment: Yes, and another browser also.